# Materialize material_select is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

This is my first time asking a question on here as I was unable to find an answer to my issue. I am using materialize and trying to use material_select(). Here is my main page that has the jQuery and materialize library as well as `document.ready` calls to both `sidenav()` and `material_select()`. Sidenav works just fine, yet `material_select()` is throwing an Uncaught TypeError.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
    $("#slide-out").sidenav();
    $("select").material_select();
});
</script>
```

Here is the html where I use select:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field">
        <select name="status" id="selectedTest">
            <option value="public" selected>Public</option>
            <option value="private">Private</option>
            <option value="unpublished">Unpublished</option>
        </select>
        <label for="status">Status</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function
>   at HTMLDocument.$.ready (dashboard:80)
>   at mightThrow (jquery-3.2.1.js:3583)
>   at process (jquery-3.2.1.js:3651)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

it should be `formSelect()` rather than `material_select()` as you are using `1.0.0` if i am not wrong according to [**`Docs`**](http://materializecss.com/select.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slide-out").sidenav();
  $("#selectedTest").formSelect();
});
```

```html
Here is the html where I use select:

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field">
    <select name="status" id="selectedTest">
      <option value="public" selected>Public</option>
      <option value="private">Private</option>
      <option value="unpublished">Unpublished</option>
    </select>
    <label for="status">Status</label>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I must have been looking at old docs. This stumped me for long than it should have.

Comment: it happens, glad i could help you out @KaneJM

Answer (score 3):

try it 
works with me 
I use materialize 1.0.0-beta

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
   var options = document.querySelectorAll('option');
   var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options); })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in your script part

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.mdb-select').materialSelect();
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).materialSelect is not a function`